# How to get the name of <T> from generic type and pass it into JsonProperty()?

Tags: c#, json.net

I get the following error with the code below:

> "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or
>   property 'Response.PropName'"

Code:

```
public class Response<T> : Response
{
    private string PropName
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(T).Name;
        }
    }            
    [JsonProperty(PropName)]
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: attributes require constant values.

Comment: @DanielA.White more precisely, **constant** values.

Comment: This can't work; attributes need constant values, and your `PropName` property is only evaluated at runtime

Comment: i wonder if theres a pure json.net solution here or some extension in its flexiblility.

Comment: Related: [Json.NET getting generic property types name on serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26629430/json-net-getting-generic-property-types-name-on-serialization).

Answer (score 9):

What you're trying to do is possible, but not trivial, and can't be done with only the built-in attributes from JSON.NET. You'll need a custom attribute, and a custom contract resolver.

Here's the solution I came up with:

Declare this custom attribute:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
class JsonPropertyGenericTypeNameAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int TypeParameterPosition { get; }

    public JsonPropertyGenericTypeNameAttribute(int position)
    {
        TypeParameterPosition = position;
    }
}
```

Apply it to your `Data` property

```
public class Response<T> : Response
{
    [JsonPropertyGenericTypeName(0)]
    public T Data { get; set; }
}
```

(0 is the position of `T` in `Response<T>`'s generic type parameters)

Declare the following contract resolver, which will look for the `JsonPropertyGenericTypeName` attribute and get the actual name of the type argument:

```
class GenericTypeNameContractResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        var prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        var attr = member.GetCustomAttribute<JsonPropertyGenericTypeNameAttribute>();
        if (attr != null)
        {
            var type = member.DeclaringType;
            if (!type.IsGenericType)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"{type} is not a generic type");
            if (type.IsGenericTypeDefinition)
                throw new InvalidOperationException($"{type} is a generic type definition, it must be a constructed generic type");
            var typeArgs = type.GetGenericArguments();
            if (attr.TypeParameterPosition >= typeArgs.Length)
                throw new ArgumentException($"Can't get type argument at position {attr.TypeParameterPosition}; {type} has only {typeArgs.Length} type arguments");
            prop.PropertyName = typeArgs[attr.TypeParameterPosition].Name;
        }
        return prop;
    }
}
```

Serialize with this resolver in your serialization settings:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { ContractResolver = new GenericTypeNameContractResolver() };
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response, settings);
```

This will give the following output for `Response<Foo>`

```
{
  "Foo": {
    "Id": 0,
    "Name": null
  }
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Works also for having List<T> inside MyClass<T>...
In my case I did not want to be dependent on the the name of T (in case someone decides to rename it), but rather used constant field in T:


`prop.PropertyName = typeArgs[0].GetField("nameInJson").GetRawConstantValue().ToString();`

Answer (score 3):

Here's a potentially easier way to achieve it.  All you need to do is to have Response extend JObject, like this:

```
public class Response<T>: Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject
{
    private static string TypeName = (typeof(T)).Name;

    private T _data;

    public T Data {
        get { return _data; }
        set {
            _data = value;
            this[TypeName] = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.FromObject(_data);   
        }
    }
}
```

If you do that, the following would work as you expect:

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var p1 = new  Response<Int32>();
        p1.Data = 5;
        var p2 = new Response<string>();
        p2.Data = "Message";


        Console.Out.WriteLine("First: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p1));
        Console.Out.WriteLine("Second: " + JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p2));
    }
```

Output:

```
First: {"Int32":5}
Second: {"String":"Message"}
```

In case you can't have `Response<T>` extend JObject, because you really need it to extend Response,  you could have Response itself extend JObject, and then have `Response<T>` extend Response as before.  It should work just the same.

Comment: That's a creative solution, but "All you need to do is to have Response extend JObject" is a pretty big requirement...

Comment: Well,  if Response can't be extended,  he can use composition and create a similar Container<T> class that would be a property of Response<T>.  I'll try to add an example later...

Answer (score 0):

@Thomas Levesque:  OK.  So let's say that you can't extend JObject in `Response<T>` because you need to extend a pre-existing Response class.   Here's another way you could implement the same solution:

```
public class Payload<T> : Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject  {
    private static string TypeName = (typeof(T)).Name;
    private T _data;

    public T Data {
        get { return _data; }
        set {
            _data = value;
            this[TypeName] = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JToken.FromObject(_data);
        }
    }
}

 //Response is a pre-existing class...
public class Response<T>: Response { 
    private Payload<T> Value;

    public Response(T arg)  {
        Value = new Payload<T>() { Data = arg };            
    }

    public static implicit operator JObject(Response<T> arg) {
        return arg.Value;
    }

    public string Serialize() {
        return Value.ToString();
    }
}
```

So now there are the following options to Serialize the class:

```
   static void Main(string[] args) {
        var p1 = new Response<Int32>(5);
        var p2 = new Response<string>("Message");
        JObject p3 = new Response<double>(0.0);
        var p4 = (JObject) new Response<DateTime>(DateTime.Now);

        Console.Out.WriteLine(p1.Serialize());
        Console.Out.WriteLine(p2.Serialize());
        Console.Out.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p3));
        Console.Out.WriteLine(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(p4));
    }
```

The Output will look something like this:

```
{"Int32":5}
{"String":"Message"}
{"Double":0.0}
{"DateTime":"2016-08-25T00:18:31.4882199-04:00"}
```

Comment: what if i only have 1 unknown parameter and others that are known? such as:  public class ReturnResponse<T>
    {  
        [JsonProperty("status")]
        public Result status { get; set; }

         private static string TypeName = (typeof(T)).Name;

        private T _data;

        public T Data
        {
            get { return _data; }
            set
            {
                _data = value;
                this[TypeName] = JToken.FromObject(_data);
            }
        }
    } - only returns the generic data and ignores the status parameter