# How to deserialize JSON wrapped collection property to generic class?

Tags: c#, json, generics, json.net, deserialization

## The problem

Many RESTful JSON APIs return *collections wrapped in an object*.
In this case along with another property which contains the number of items in the collection.

Two examples:

```
{
    "animals": [
        {"name": "Raven", "wings": 2},
        {"name": "Wolf", "wings": 0}
    ],
    "count": 2
}
```

```
{
    "vehicles": [
        {"type": "Car", "wheels": 4},
        {"type": "Motorcycle", "wheels": 2}
        {"type": "Boat", "wheels": 0}
    ],
    "count": 3
}
```

Note that these root objects are not the same because they *contain the name of the collection*.

This is not a problem in a weakly typed language such as JavaScript, but in strongly typed languages this becomes a problem if there are a lot of these similar wrapper objects.

**Without generics**

Of course these could be deserialized like this:

```
class AnimalsResponse 
{
    public List<Animal> Animals { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}

class Animal
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Wings { get; set; }
}

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AnimalsResponse>(content);
```

```
class VehiclesResponse 
{
    public List<Vehicle> Vehicles { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
} 

class Vehicle
{
    public string Type { get; set; }
    public int Wheels { get; set; }
}

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<VehiclesResponse>(content);
```

**With generics**

As the root object is always in the same format, except for the name of the collection, it would be desirable to deserialize to a generic type:

```
class CollectionResponse<T>
{
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

## (Possibly overly complicated) solution

I already tried (successfully) to do this with a custom deserializer, but this solution seems overly complicated for such a common problem.

```
class CollectionJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    private readonly string collectionName;

    public CollectionJsonConverter(string collectionName) : base()
    {
        this.collectionName = collectionName ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(collectionName));
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsGenericType && 
            objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(CollectionResponse<>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, 
        Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);

        var objectProperties = objectType.GetTypeInfo().DeclaredProperties.ToList();
        var objectProperty = objectProperties.FirstOrDefault(pi =>
            pi.Name == nameof(CollectionResponse<object>.Items));

        var jsonProperties = JObject.Load(reader).Properties();
        var jsonProperty = jsonProperties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == collectionName);

        objectProperty?.SetValue(instance, 
            jsonProperty.Value.ToObject(objectProperty.PropertyType, new JsonSerializer()));

        return instance;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CollectionResponse<T>>(content, new CollectionJsonConverter(collectionName));
```

Where collectionName is the name of the collection (like `"animals"` or `"vehicles"` in the above examples).
This unfortunately adds an extra parameter to deal with.

### The question

Is there a simpler way to achieve this, preferably without a custom deserializer?

Comment: You can do it with a custom contract resolver.  See: [Json.NET getting generic property types name on serialization?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26629430) and [How to get the name of `<T>` from generic type and pass it into JsonProperty()?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39129145).  Not sure that counts as "simpler" though.  There's no way to do this entirely through attributes.

Comment: Depending on your requirements, maybe this is what you can do: `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CollectionResponse<Animal>>(ReplaceFirstOccurrence(content, "animals", "items"));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no way to do what you are asking without either a custom `JsonConverter` or a custom `ContractResolver`.  I think the `JsonConverter` is actually a good approach here, but you can simplify it quite a bit so that you don't need to pass in the collection name and you don't need reflection to set the `Items` property:

```
class CollectionJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType.IsGenericType &&
            objectType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(CollectionResponse<>);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader,
        Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        // load the JSON into a JObject
        var obj = JObject.Load(reader);

        // we expect one and only one list of items; don't care what its name is
        var itemsProp = obj.Properties().Single(p => p.Value.Type == JTokenType.Array);

        // replace the existing list property with a new one called "Items"
        itemsProp.Replace(new JProperty("Items", itemsProp.Value));

        // create an instance of the CollectionResponse model
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(objectType);

        // populate it from the modified JObject
        serializer.Populate(obj.CreateReader(), instance);

        return instance;
    }

    public override bool CanWrite => false;

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Also, you can decorate your `CollectionResponse<T>` class with a `[JsonConverter]` attribute to tie the converter to the class so that you never need to worry about passing the converter when you deserialize:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(CollectionJsonConverter))]
class CollectionResponse<T>
{
    public List<T> Items { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can just deserialize like this (for example):

```
var vehiclesResp = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CollectionResponse<Vehicle>>(vehiclesJson);
```

Working demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/D3q8ub

Comment: Thanks. Not everything in your code example will work in my real wold application (my example was a bit too simplified), but these are some useful pointers.

Comment: Glad I could help.